# Snap application not starting due to "AppArmor policy"

Tags: 18.04, snap, apparmor

I installed a snap application (Bookworm) through the software center. The installation process seemed to go fine, but nothing happened when I try to launch it through the GUI. Here's what happens when I use the terminal:

```
calixte@Ceres:~$ bookworm
[INFO 12:04:45.135623] Application.vala:154: Bookworm version: (null)
[INFO 12:04:45.135687] Application.vala:156: Kernel version: 4.15.0-21-generic
[WARNING 12:04:45.135986] [Gtk] Locale not supported by C library.  Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.165" is not allowed to own the service "com.github.babluboy.bookworm" due to AppArmor policy
```

What can I do to fix that error and make the app run? Alternatively, can I change the general AppArmor policy?

Comment: Please post the extra questions as different posts. Too many different questions in a single post make it too broad. Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/70524 for why you don't want the C locale to be the default.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the same as you after setting my system to the US English locale and the problem persists even there, so I looked a bit further, but unfortunately for you [it's a bug](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/issues/178) and the workaround is to install bookworm using two methods on Ubuntu:

1. Install from the stable PPA
2. Install from Flatpak

Instructions for both of the above are [here](https://babluboy.github.io/bookworm/#install)

## Sorry! :-(